# Mongodb: $gt and $lt in Javascript (Meteor) isn't working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

**UPDATE:** Problem is **solved**, the problem was sitting in front of the monitor. I've called this via a test function and both variables (`startSegment` and `endSegment`) were string parameter. The parse didn't catch that somehow. Thanks to everyone helping.

I can run the query in the MongoDb shell with the correct answer (two records) and it also works when I replace the values that I use in $gt and $lt with the absolute values, like in this example:

```
res = Matches.find(
  { chr: chr , 
    start: {$lt: 12103392}, 
    end: {$gt: 9381380}, 
    $or: [
      {kit1: kitnoA }, 
      {kit2: kitnoA }
    ]
  });
```

However when I replace the two absolute values with local variables it returns not a single document:

```
res = Matches.find(
  { chr: chr, 
    end: {$gt: startSegment}, 
    start: {$lt: endSegment}, 
    $or: [
      {kit1: kitnoA }, 
      {kit2: kitnoA }
    ]
  });

  res.forEach(function (doc) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
  });
```

I've checked the MongoDb documentation (eg here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/query/lt/) to no avail. Also searches on the internet and SO didn't produce any good lead.

I've also tried the $where operator though that one would clearly have a huge disadvantage in performance (can't use indexes and has to do a full table scan) but it also didn't work and ignored the $where clause completely (it selected all documents which qualify the other criteria:

```
res = Matches.find( 
  {chr: chr}, 
  {$where: "this.start < endSegment || this.end > startSegment"}, 
  {$or: [
    {kit1: kitnoA }, 
    {kit2: kitnoA }
  ]
});
```

There is no index defined on this collection other than the system index on _id

I'm puzzled why it doesn't work at all with variables. Using Meteor version 1.1.0.3 which uses MongoDb version 2.6.7

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Did you check that `startSegment` and `endSegment` are actually available and they have value?

Comment: Yes and I even renamed the original variables `end` and `start` as I thought that the same name usage would cause a problem.

Comment: And do the numbers make sense? I mean did you put the right variable in the right place? I know, I know, but still if you are too tired :)

Comment: Yes, I've put two working examples above. One is just by replacing the two variables with their real values, that works. The other one is the MongoDb shell command which also works. I also tried switching the two $lt and $gt statements around (that was an early MongoDb but 3 years ago) but it didn't made any difference. I've spent 7h on this until now so I tried every possible combination. Hence I could narrow it down to the $lt and $gt statement and that it somehow has to do with the variables that I'm checking there.

Comment: Are you using that query on the client or on the server? And does `console.log(Matches.find().count())` log a non-zero number?

Comment: Could it be that `startSegment` is not a number? Have you tried `parseInt(startSegment, 10)`?

Comment: it's running on the server and there are currently 509 documents in Matches collection with 41 of them qualifying for chr:1 - @OliverLloyd yes, they are numbers and adding your `parseInt` statement doesn't bring any change (still no document returned)

Comment: I'm curious if you run `console.log(Matches.find().count())` in your meteor application, what you get. Do you get 509?

Comment: Yes, it's actually executed at the start of the app for all collections so that I know how many documents I have in each collection. This isn't the problem, the problem is clearly about how the variables 'endSegment' and 'startSegment' are being translated for MongoDb by Meteor

Comment: I have queries that use `$gte` on the server with passed in variables that work in Meteor v1.2.1 so I doubt this is a Meteor specific issue. I'd be surprised if there was a difference between `$gt` and `$gte`.

Comment: Working Meteor query: 
`{
  '_id': someVariable,
  deleted: false,
  modified: {
    $gte: since || 0
  },
};`

Comment: Checking some more, I proved out that Meteor definately handles the `$gt` operator. You might want to cut and paste something similar to the following to your console and see what you get:
`var since = 9999999999999999;
MyCollection.find({modified: {$gt: since}}).forEach(function(item){console.log(item)})
var since = 123;
MyCollection.find({modified: {$gt: since}}).forEach(function(item){console.log(item)})
{_id: "g6XeiRnrxdKNnySds"...}
{_id: "qGSxtXTn5yjkdnEQx"...}`
Then you can add change it to try and find the point where it stops working.

Comment: Thanks Serkan and Oliver. How can I close this thread so that no further answers or comments can be edited? Or is it even possible to delete it?